# Unable to find any info about the SMPS IC

Tags: integrated-circuit, switch-mode-power-supply

Below is the image of SMPS IC. I am reverse engineering a SMPS AC DC converter and find out this IC. But unfortunately, I am unable find any link or datasheet for this.

Can anybody help me in getting any useful information about this IC.

[image]

Comment: Might be a custom marked part. You're best off sketching out the whole schematic. Once you've done this, take a look at Power Integrations, Richtek and similar companies that make this type of 8-pin, low-cost, high volume ICs popular in AC adapters and see if you have a matching schematic.

Comment: Here's a very informative paper on an example design from Power Integrations. OEMs often start with these example designs and then make it as cheap as possible: https://ac-dc.power.com/sites/default/files/PDFFiles/rdr462.pdf

Answer (score 1):

> I am reverse engineering a SMPS AC DC converter

Why do this when there are several (plenty) of designs out there with full designs and specifications for all the wound components and sometimes PCB layouts too. I'm thinking here of a company called Power Integrations - they make a very wide range of SMPS power supplies and another company called Premier Magnetics design (and supply) many, many wound components for the PI chips. PM also supply wound components for TI chips. See [this](http://www.premiermag.com/html/product-family/power-magnetics.html) page.

So, if I just take [one example](http://www.premiermag.com/pdf/POL-xxxxx2.pdf) using the PM route I get a list of over 100 UL-CSA recognized designs ranging from low voltage to high voltage and low power to high power. Each one links to a specific design and importantly gives you a schematic and a supply reference for the transformer.

You can also use PI's site to design your own transformer.

So why bother reverse engineering something you have because, that power supply you are reverse engineering: -

- May not have a universal supply voltage input range
- May not have proper/adequate EMC
- May have clearance/isolation that is not be good enough for new designs
- May have other ambiguous components that you mistakenly identify
- May not be very good in ways you have not considered.